# Wandb API endpoint URL/IP address and port?

Tags: authentication, endpoint, wandb

I am trying to use wandb on a institution managed HPC system. Unfortunately internet is not available by default (probably blocked by firewall).

When I have requested a way for me to use wandb, they have asked me to provide the **IP and port** and they might be able to help.

I was wondering if anyone knows what should be the IP/port that wandb uses when sending the data and authentication request.